# Query to join and count rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two table portal and login table.How to get count of portal_id in login table and join with portal table. If there is no matching row exists in login table show as null value

```
    $this->db->select("a.name");
    $this->db->from("{$this->Portal} a");
    $this->db->join("{$this->login} b","a.id = b.portal_id");
    $this->db->order_by("a.portal_id asc");
```

Table **portal**

```
id  |  name
1   |  john
2   |  steve
3   |  ricky
4   |  richard
```

Table **Login**

```
portal_id | city
1         | Bangalore
2         | Ludhiana 
1         | Chandighara
2         | Delhi
```

Result Table

```
id    |  name | count
1     | john  | 2
2     | steve | 2
3     | ricky | null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple left join needs to be used, to get the counts as null instead of zero you can use nullif

```
    select p.id,
    p.name,
    NULLIF(count(l.portal_id), 0) as 
    portal_logn_count
    from portal p left join login l on p.id = 
    l.portal_id
    group by p.id,p.name
    order by p.id,p.name
```

Comment: does this work with pagination count. where limit and offset are used

Comment: It should, I dont have a php setup ready at my end but it works at the front end that I use

Comment: In paginatoin i need to fetch total number of records . How to fetch total number of records with group by

Comment: @BLPraveen: `select count(distinct id from portal)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(l.id) AS `count`
FROM portal p
LEFT JOIN Login l ON l.portal_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select("a.id,a.name,count(a.id)");
$this->db->from("{$this->Portal} a");
$this->db->join("{$this->login} b","a.id = b.portal_id", 'left');
$this->db->group_by("a.id");
$this->db->order_by("a.id asc");
```

Making a query like

```
Select a.id, a.name, count(a.id) from portal a
left join login b on a.id = b.portal_id
group by a.id
order by a.id asc
```

Comment: How to get total no of records

Answer (score 1):

Works Perfectly....

```
    Select a.id, a.name, NULLIF(count(b.portal_id ), 0) from portal a
    left join Login b on a.id = b.portal_id 
    group by a.id
    order by a.id asc
```

Comment: How to get the total no of records